MS Word replaces my Normal.dotm template with a temporary file when saving
When I save changes to my template file (Normal.dotm) in Word 365, as of a few days ago, it changes the name to "~WRL0022.dotm" (the exact number may vary). I can't find anyplace on my drive where this file exists (even searching for hidden and system files). Then when I exit Word, sometimes it saves this temporary file back to Normal.dotm, and sometimes it simply throws my changes away (AARGH!). It does this regardless of whether I am editing another file (so there are two "projects" in the VBA editor, even if one stays empty), or if I only have a blank file open.
Changes made to other Word documents' macros save normally ("Filename.docm" gets saved without a name change. Only edits to "Normal.docm" get this problem.)
Again, it didn't behave like this until recently.
Has this happened to anyone else?

How are you making edits?  Specifically, are you opening up a blank Word doc, going into VBA and updating the Normal project, or is there a file you're opening up and making the changes with (and if so, what is the extension)?

Cyril: added answer to post.

Still not that clear...  Starting with Word not running, what exact steps are you taking to edit Normal.dotm when you're seeing the problem described?

OK. I launch Word.
I choose a blank, new document. I enter the VBA Editor with Ctrl+F11.  I add a space to a line ending. I press the Save button in the toolbar. The Editor's title bar changes the name from "Normal.dotm" to "~WRL0022.dotm".
I close Word. I open a Word document, that may or may not have macros. I enter the VBA Editor with Ctrl+F11.  I add a space to a line ending in the Normal.dotm macros (NOT the newly opened document). I press the Save button in the toolbar. The Editor's title bar changes the name from "Normal.dotm" to "~WRL0022.dotm".

Just tried the same steps at home, using the same license, but on my home computer - the problem exists on my work laptop.
At home it doesn't happen. Saving the Normal.dotm macros just saves Normal.dotm. As one would expect.

Copied the Normal.dotm FROM my work laptop TO my home desktop, overwriting the home version. The problem still does not repeat at home.

FWIW I have also seen similar problems, including the renaming that you describe in the VBE. Probably just coincidence but I only saw it on a Windows 11 system. That was a couple of months ago and could have started earlier. Haven't had the need or time to investigate.
